# Cloning a 1GB+ repo from BitBucket into SourceTree taking forever

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have a repo that is on Bitbucket.com and is very large (over 1Gb) - when I try to clone this using SourceTree it states it is cloning & the application hasn't crashed but it has been over an hour (my internet connection is a fast broadband so this isn't the problem).

Is there a command I can run to verify that the cloning process is working and it is just a case of waiting?

Comment: If you click the "Terminal" button and clone the repo using the command line, you'll get a progress indicator that shows what % of the repo has been downloaded so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in git tool for that. I would recommend to to check the size of `.git` directory.

Eg, in Linux you can do it like this:

```
du -sh .git
```

or to watch the size for live updates:

```
watch du -sh .git
```